# utilizando MySQLi dentro de CLASS

Tags: php, mysqli

Olá, estou com problema, tenho algumas consultas para fazer, queria deixar dentro de class, estou fazendo o seguinte código:

```
<?php
class MySQL {
    private $user;
    private $password;
    private $database;
    private $host;

    public function __construct($user, $password, $database, $host="localhost"){
        $this->user     =   $user;
        $this->password =   $password;
        $this->database =   $database;
        $this->host     =   $host;

        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die('FATAL ERROR: Can not connect to SQL Server.');
            exit();
        }
    }

    public function _query($qr)
    {
        $this->result = $this->mysqli->query($qr);
        return $this->result;
    }

    public function _close()
    {
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }
}
```

Para chamar, faço:

```
    <?php
        session_start();
        $connect = new MySQL(UserMySQL, PassMySQL, DataBaseMySQL, ServerMySQL);
function test(){
        $search =   $connect->_query("SELECT value FROM tab2 WHERE type='".$type."'");
        $search =   $connect->_query("SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE urlName='".$subName."'");
    }
    test();
```

Porém me retorna erro.
**Call to a member function _query() on a non-object in** ..........

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro, parece que a conexão falhou, da um `var_dump($connect);`

Comment: @rray object(MySQL)#1 (5) { ["user":"MySQL":private]=> string(15) "user" ["password":"MySQL":private]=> string(12) "password" ["database":"MySQL":private]=> string(15) "database" ["host":"MySQL":private]=> string(9) "localhost" ["mysqli"]=> object(mysqli)#2 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=> string(6) "5.5.49" ["client_version"]=> int(50549) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=>string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket" ["info"]=>  .....................

Comment: @rray ............................  NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=> string(10) "5.5.50-cll" ["server_version"]=> int(50550) ["stat"]=> string(155) "Uptime: 415835 Threads: 13 Questions: 1647446872 Slow queries: 178 Opens: 3500320 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 2750 Queries per second avg: 3961.780" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(6998409) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } }

Comment: É concordo que o problema pode ser na conexão. E para ficar mais fácil de  detectar erros, na construct seria melhor deixar apenas a instancia das variáveis. Criar um método apenas para conexão e chamá-lo assim que instanciar a classe.

Comment: Copie, colei, alterei os dados do banco e da consulta e não retornou erro, o problema parece estar em outro lugar.

Comment: O teste que vc fez foi esse q adicinou na edição? pq não vai funcionar dessa forma

Comment: @rray e Débora muito obrigado pelas dicas, consegui resolver, e já publiquei explicando, obrigado mesmo!!!!!

Comment: Por isso é bacana sempre postar o código real, as vezes ocultar alguns detalhes na pergunta dificultam de detectar o problema.

Comment: @rray Verdade... vivendo e aprendendo né?  não farei novamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou declarar variável $connect global dentro da função, dessa maneira:

```
function test(){
    global $connect;
    $search =   $connect->_query("SELECT value FROM tab2 WHERE type='".$type."'");
    $search =   $connect->_query("SELECT * FROM tab1 WHERE urlName='".$subName."'");
}
```

Peço perdão a comunidade por cometer este erro, enfim, agora quem tiver essa dúvida saberá hahaha

Comment: Isso mesmo o problema era o escopo da variável. Tem outra forma de resolver isso, passe o `$connect` na assinatura da função `function test($connect){ ...`